# Pass STL containers from Flex to Bison

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I'm writing a scanner/parser combination using Flex and Bison, if possible I would like to avoid using C++ specific features of both programs but nevertheless I need to access a C++ library from the source file generated by Bison. At the moment I'm compiling the source file generated by Flex as a C program.

One thing I thought I might be able to do is to declare STL type members inside Bison's `%union` statement, e.g.:

```
%union {
  std::string str;
};
```

I quickly realized that this cannot work because this produces a union that is included by the Flex source file. I then thought I might just compile that with a C++ compiler as well but the statement above is already rejected when running bison:

```
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘std’
```

I don't really want to go through the trouble of copying and concatenating strings with C stdlib functions throughout my parser. What can I do in order to make the scanner return STL types to the parser?

EDIT: the linked duplicate does not really answer my question, the answers to that one only show how to compile both files using a C++ compiler which is not my issue.

Comment: I think I have given up at this point, Bison's C++ Interface is a nightmare and all "minimal" examples found online are anything but. I'll just stick to using C types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly compile both your generated scanner and parser with C++, even if you use the default C skeletons (and I agree that the C++ skeletons are badly documented and excessively complicated). So there is nothing stopping you from using `std::string` inside your parser.

However, that won't let you put a `std::string` inside a `union`, because you can't just toss a class with a non-trivial destructor into a `union`. It's possible to work around this limitation by explicitly declaring the semantic type and providing explicit constructors and destructors, but it's going to be a fair amount of work and it may well not be worth it.

That still leaves you with a couple of options. One is to use a pointer to a `std::string`, which means that your scanner action has to do something like:

```
[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]*    yylval.strval = new std::string(yytext);
```

Another one is to just use C strings, leading to:

```
[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]*    yylval.strval = strdup(yytext);
```

In both cases, you'll end up having to manually manage the allocated memory; C++'s smart pointers won't help you because they also have non-trivial destructors, so they can't be easily shoe-horned into semantic unions either.

Since it appears that you're going to eventually make the token into a `std::string`, you might as well do it from the start using the first option above. Since most tokens are short and most C++ libraries now implement a short string optimization, `new std::string(yytext)` will frequently require only one memory allocation (and if it requires two, the library will transparently handle the second one).

Comment: I'm currently going with the second option which is still okay since my grammar is not that complicated, of course that means that string concatenation is  a little more involved and I have to manually free memory but that is not that bad. I don't see how I would use your first suggestion though because it bison also complains if put a pointer to `std::string` inside `%union`.

Comment: @Peter:  I've never seen an error from bison for putting `std::string *` in the `%union`.  The error you reproduce looks like it comes from a C compiler, not bison.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. It did not work because I was still compiling the file generated by Flex which includes that union as C code.

Comment: @Peter: a separate question is why you need string concatenation at all :) Leaving that aside, in C I use `asprintf` (or a small variant which returns the malloc'd sprintf'd string), which is almost as easy as C++ (and sometimes easier, if you need sprintf formats) but does leave you manually managing memory. Memory management is harder to work around.